# How to add variables value

Tags: jquery

Hi guys im sorry but i dont even know what the title should be i have this script that works perfectly but i had this problem that i really cant solve cause im not really that good with programming. My code simply adds the total value of the customer order somehow the value of each item is stored temporarily on div and then just dynamically print the value in it, the purpose is for me to see if the calculation is working now i am having problem as i want to remove the DIV and leave total only. Here is my code

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('input:radio[name="meal-356"]').change(function(ev){

        if ($(this).val() == 'Burger with fries') {
            var meal = 20;
        }
        else {
            var meal = 30;
        }

        $('#meal').text((meal).toFixed(2)).trigger('change');

    });

    $('input:radio[name="drinks-123"]').change(function(ev){

        if ($(this).val() == 'Ice Tea') {
            var drinks = 1;
        }
        else if ($(this).val() == 'Coke') {
            var drinks = 1.20;
        }
        else if ($(this).val() == 'Lemonade') {
            var drinks = 2;
        }
        else if ($(this).val() == 'Water') {
            var drinks = 1.75;
        }
        else if ($(this).val() == 'Hot choco') {
            var drinks = 3;
        }
        else if ($(this).val() == 'Hot coffee') {
            var drinks = 1.25;
        }
        else {
            var drinks = 0;
        }

        $('#drinks').text((drinks).toFixed(2)).trigger('change');
    });


    $('input:radio[name="extras-781"]').change(function(ev){

        if ($(this).val() == 'Rice') {
            var extras = 10;
        }
        else if ($(this).val() == 'Gravy') {
            var extras = 5;
        }
        else {
            var extras = 0;
        }
        $('#extras').text((extras).toFixed(2)).trigger('change');
    });

    $('textarea[name="spoon-112"]').keyup(function(ev){

        var spoon = $(this).val().replace(/\n/g, '<br/>');
  var spoon = spoon*.25;
        $("#spoon").text(spoon).trigger('change');

    });

    $('input:text[name="fork-143"]').keyup(function(ev){

        var fork = $(this).val().replace(/\n/g, '<br/>');
  var fork = fork*.5;
        $("#fork").text(fork).trigger('change');
    });



    $('#meal, #drinks, #extras, #spoon, #fork').on('change', function(e) {
        var total = $('#meal, #drinks, #extras, #spoon, #fork').toArray().reduce(function(acc, val) {
            return acc + +val.textContent   ;
        }, 0);
        $('#total').text(total.toFixed(2));
    })

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Calculator base on radio buttons</h1>
<h2>Question 1: meal</h2>
<div class="meal-wrapper">
    <label class="radio"><input name="meal-356" value="Burger with fries" type="radio"/>Burger with fries</label>
</div>
<div>
    <label class="radio"><input name="meal-356" value="Chicken with rice" type="radio" />Chicken with rice</label>
</div>

<h2>Question 2: drinks</h2>
<div class="drinks-123-wrapper">
    <input type="radio" name="drinks-123" value="Ice Tea" /> Ice Tea
    <input type="radio" name="drinks-123" value="Coke" /> Coke
    <input type="radio" name="drinks-123" value="Lemonade" /> Lemonade
    <input type="radio" name="drinks-123" value="Water" /> Water
    <input type="radio" name="drinks-123" value="Hot choco" /> Hot choco
    <input type="radio" name="drinks-123" value="Hot coffee" /> Hot coffee
    <input type="radio" name="drinks-123" value="No drinks-123" /> No drinks-123
</div>

<h2>Question 3: extras</h2>
<div class="drinks-wrapper">
    <input type="radio" name="extras-781" value="Rice" /> Rice
    <input type="radio" name="extras-781" value="Gravy" /> Gravy
    <input type="radio" name="extras-781" value="No Extra" /> No Extra
</div>

<h2>Question 4: How many extra spoon?</h2>
<div class="spoon-wrapper">
    <textarea name="spoon-112" rows="3"></textarea>
</div>

<h2>Question 5: How many extra fork?</h2>
<div class="fork-wrapper">
    <input name="fork-143" type="text" value="" placeholder=""/>
</div>

<hr />
<div class="price-wrapper">
    <b>meal:</b> <span id="meal"></span>
    <div></div>
    <b>drinks:</b> <span id="drinks"></span>
    <div></div>
    <b>extras:</b> <span id="extras"></span>
    <div></div>
    <b>spoon:</b> <span id="spoon"></span>
    <div></div>
    <b>fork:</b> <span id="fork"></span>
</div>

<div class="total-wrapper">
    <h3>
        <b>Total:</b><span id="total"></span>
    </h3>
</div>
```

i want to actually remove the divs with id #meal, #drinks, #extras, #spoon, #fork and just leave #total .. but the problem is it wont calculate anymore and i dont know what to do... this is the code where im stuck

```
    $('#meal, #drinks, #extras, #spoon, #fork').on('change', function(e) {
    var total = $('#meal, #drinks, #extras, #spoon, #fork').toArray().reduce(function(acc, val) {
        return acc + +val.textContent   ;
    }, 0);
    $('#total').text(total.toFixed(2));
})
```

Comment: alright sorry :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reduce your code a lot, if you would add the price information in your HTML, for instance with `data-price` attributes. But as you explained you cannot change the HTML, the second best option would be to store the prices in some object structure.

The suggested code:

```js
// Define the prices for each element selector, and with an 
// indication whether the count must be read from text
var unitPrices = [
//   element selector                       price has-count
    [":checked[value='Burger with fries']", 20.00,  0],
    [":checked[value='Chicken with rice']", 30.00,  0],
    [":checked[value='Ice Tea']",            1.00,  0],
    [":checked[value='Coke']",               1.20,  0],
    [":checked[value='Lemonade']",           2.00,  0],
    [":checked[value='Water']",              1.75,  0],
    [":checked[value='Hot choco']",          3.00,  0],
    [":checked[value='Hot coffee']",         1.25,  0],
    [":checked[value='No drinks-123']",      0.00,  0],
    [":checked[value='Rice']",              10.00,  0],
    [":checked[value='Gravy']",              5.00,  0],
    [":checked[value='No Extra']",           0.00,  0],
    ["[name=spoon-112]",                     0.25,  1],
    ["[name=fork-143]",                      0.50,  1],
];

function updateTotal() {
    // Iterate over all price elements, and apply the unit prices
    var prices = unitPrices.map(function (info) {
        var $elem = $(info[0]);
        // if the element does not match, return 0, else the price
        return $elem.length * info[1] *
            // and see if we need to read out the count        
            // if so: multiply by the entered number (ignore non-digits)
            (info[2] ? $elem.val().replace(/\D/g, '') : 1 );
    });
    // Now we have an array of prices (numbers). Total them:
    var total = prices.reduce(function(acc, val) {
        return acc + val;
    }, 0);
    // Display the total:
    $('#total').text(total.toFixed(2));
}

$(function() {
    // Update the total on any change to input elements:
    $(':input').on('input change', updateTotal);
    // Also call it once when the page loads:
    updateTotal();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Calculator base on radio buttons</h1>
<h2>Question 1: meal</h2>
<div class="meal-wrapper">
    <label class="radio"><input name="meal-356" value="Burger with fries" type="radio"/>Burger with fries</label>
</div>
<div>
    <label class="radio"><input name="meal-356" value="Chicken with rice" type="radio" />Chicken with rice</label>
</div>

<h2>Question 2: drinks</h2>
<div class="drinks-123-wrapper">
    <input type="radio" name="drinks-123" value="Ice Tea" /> Ice Tea
    <input type="radio" name="drinks-123" value="Coke" /> Coke
    <input type="radio" name="drinks-123" value="Lemonade" /> Lemonade
    <input type="radio" name="drinks-123" value="Water" /> Water
    <input type="radio" name="drinks-123" value="Hot choco" /> Hot choco
    <input type="radio" name="drinks-123" value="Hot coffee" /> Hot coffee
    <input type="radio" name="drinks-123" value="No drinks-123" /> No drinks-123
</div>

<h2>Question 3: extras</h2>
<div class="drinks-wrapper">
    <input type="radio" name="extras-781" value="Rice" /> Rice
    <input type="radio" name="extras-781" value="Gravy" /> Gravy
    <input type="radio" name="extras-781" value="No Extra" /> No Extra
</div>

<h2>Question 4: How many extra spoons?</h2>
<div class="spoon-wrapper">
    <textarea name="spoon-112" rows="3" ></textarea>
</div>

<h2>Question 5: How many extra forks?</h2>
<div class="fork-wrapper">
    <input name="fork-143" type="text" value="" placeholder=""/>
</div>

<hr />
<div class="total-wrapper">
    <h3>
        <b>Total:</b><span id="total"></span>
    </h3>
</div>
```

Make sure to run the snippet in full-page mode.

Comment: ok sorry to mention that i cant change the input or add extra tag on input tags since i dont have access on it, they are generated randomly.. i only have access to my DIVS and my jquery code .. sorry

Comment: i can see that it only change the total when i entered something on textarea.. but i am able to understand the code now :D

Comment: Are you saying the total does not change when you check a radio button? Which browser are you running on? If indeed you only get the total recalculated when you enter in the textarea, then add the `change` event in the `on` method. I updated my answer.

Comment: well that worked :D thanks a lot.. i'm still trying to figure out this shorten code of yours.. thanks for your time..

Comment: by the way i just thought is there anyway that i can just use index instead of typing the whole value .. lets say instead of if ($(this).val() == 'Ice Tea') i'll use if ($(drinks).index(this) == 0)

Comment: Yes, but do you really prefer doing like 10 `if`s? And what if the page is changed and gets a new product inserted in the middle of the list. Then you have to check each `if` to see it uses the correct index.

Comment: you mean if i use index i will be using if?

Comment: I just refer to what you wrote, where you mentioned an `if` yourself in: `if ($(drinks).index(this) == 0)`. You can use `index` without `if`, but I don't really understand why you would want to. It will be less obvious which item has which price, and so maintaining the code will be harder.

Comment: so i dont have to type the very long value like "Burger with fries" all i have to do is find the index cause the value doesnt change anyway just the price.. i have control over the price but the value like "Burger with fries" is always the same

Comment: Sure, it is possible. It would be much different from this solution. Have a go at it. If you bump into an issue, don't hesitate to ask help via a new question.

Comment: perhaps i should just re ask and modify and make my question more clear so everyone would understand what im trying to accomplish .. since english is not my native language its really hard for me to explain .. anyway i'll open a new question and ask again .. thanks for your time i really do appreciate it

Comment: If you ask a new question, paste the link to it here, and I'll have a look. Good luck.

Comment: i added a new question hope i wont get banned by doing that :( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42740497/jquery-adding-variables-and-making-script-short

Comment: I will have a look, but I see you have many sub-questions in there. I hope someone will find the time to answer all of that ;-)

Comment: all the questions i asked was answered and little by little i accomplished what i was trying to do with their answer. :D

Answer (score 0):

The data you need to calculate the total from are stored in the ids you want to remove. So don't delete them from the DOM else the values can't be retrieved to calculate your total. Why not just leave them there and hide it via CSS?

```
<div class="price-wrapper" style="display: none;">
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/2emum57m/

Comment: yes i already did that but code is too ugly so somehow i want a shorter code.. i know it can be done i just dont know how.. lol thanks for the answer btw

Comment: Oic, you want to simplify your code. I suggest you work on those `if` blocks in the input onChange event listeners first. If you can, place the values into the inputs. Otherwise, use an object to act as a map to fetch and retrieve those values. Also, to remove the ids, you need to not store data in them with those `.text()`. Create an `updateTotal(amount)` function to call at the end of each input onChange event instead.

Comment: ok will try to do that .. lol im not even sure where to put the code.. im terribly sorry